# Using C# expressions in WPF binding

Tags: c#, javascript, wpf, mvvm

Consider that my `ViewModel` has the `IsBusy` propery. Is it possible to have such binding in WPF?

```
<ProgressBar Visiblity="{Binding IsBusy}" ... />
<Button Visiblity="{Binding !IsBusy}" .../>
```

Note that I've bound `Button`'s visibility to `!IsBusy` (Not Busy).

I used to have this on `JavaScript` MVVM frameworks like `knockout`.

The expression could be more complex like:

```
<Button Text="IsBusy && !HasError ? true : false"/>
```

Comment: Use [IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @RohitVats It's too hard to create IValueConverters for all combinations required. Isn't there a more JavaScript like solution!?

Comment: You cannot have what does not exist.  You can, of course, create your own custom binding that parses and attempts to execute the text passed to the binding.  Which would probably not be too crazy with the coming of Roslyn.  But it makes no sense to argue for the existence of something that doesn't exist.  Even though, GOTDAMNIT, it would be super sweet if some fat guy would slide down my chimney and leave me some swag.  Wouldn't that be awesome?  This should exist!  Tell me he exists!

Comment: @Will maybe I should post another question about creating custom bindings. As I'm familiar with Roslyn, it wouldn't be so hard achieve what I want.

Comment: Bindings are trivial to make.  Try doing it before asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In WPF you need to bind to a property so you cannot do `!Busy` as you wanted. If you want some complex conditions you should create a specific property for that. If you want to have your output formatted in specific way, you can implement custom value converter (i.e. implement interface IValueConverter).